# Copy columns which meet a specific criteria to a new sheet

Tags: vba

im using this code and it works but somehow stops after the first row is copied. Do you have an idea why? Otherwise it seems to do what it should do, thanks! The searched term is nosh and in sheet 1 (Tabelle1) it is always found in this format D:XXX(NOSH) with XXX changing for different company names.

```
Public Sub Kopieren() 

Dim WkSh_Q As Worksheet 
Dim WkSh_Z As Worksheet 
Dim rZelle As Range 
Dim aUeberschr As Variant 
Dim iIndx As Integer 
Dim iSpalte As Integer 

aUeberschr = Array("NOSH") 

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

Set WkSh_Q = Worksheets("Tabelle1") ' das Quell-Tabellenblatt 
Set WkSh_Z = Worksheets("Tabelle2") ' das Ziel-Tabellenblatt 

With WkSh_Q.Rows
For iIndx = 0 To UBound(aUeberschr) 
Set rZelle = .Find(aUeberschr(iIndx), LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) 
If Not rZelle Is Nothing Then 
iSpalte = iSpalte + 1 
WkSh_Q.Columns(rZelle.Column).Copy Destination:=WkSh_Z.Columns(iSpalte) 
End If 
Next iIndx 
End With 

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 

End Sub
```

Edit:

And I would need to copy every coloumn with NOSH to be copied to "Tabelle2"

I found this Code to search the whole first sheet and repeat the task but it seems to copy just the names of the stocks (BAYER etc) to every row.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 

Dim WkSh_Q As Worksheet, WkSh_Z As Worksheet 
Dim rZelle As Range, aUeberschr As Variant 
Dim strErste As String 
Dim iIndx As Long, iSpalte As Long 

aUeberschr = Array(NOSH) 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

Set WkSh_Q = Worksheets("Tabelle1") ' das Quell-Tabellenblatt 
Set WkSh_Z = Worksheets("Tabelle2") ' das Ziel-Tabellenblatt 

With WkSh_Q.Cells 
    For iIndx = 0 To UBound(aUeberschr) 
        Set rZelle = .Find(aUeberschr(iIndx), LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) 
        If Not rZelle Is Nothing Then 
            strErste = rZelle.Address 
            Do 
                iZeile = iZeile + 1 
                WkSh_Q.Rows(rZelle.Row).Copy Destination:=WkSh_Z.Rows(iZeile) 
                Set rZelle = .FindNext(rZelle) 
            Loop Until strErste = rZelle.Address 
        End If 
    Next iIndx 
End With 

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of what your data looks like in Tabelle1 and the desired result in Tabelle2?

Comment: it only looks at the first row with `With WkSh_Q.Rows(1)`

Comment: Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/jsqMNJS.jpg Here is the screenshot I cant post it above as I need 10 reputation.

Comment: And yes the (1) was wrong so I changed that, the question that remains is a) Why does the second code copy only the first row of each coloumn and fills the coloumns in sheet2 with them and/or b) how could I update the first code so it continue the copying of every coloumn which contains the word NOSH in the second row. Im thankful for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the second code you posted. I "cleaned" up the code a bit and also modified the code to do your desired task. When you are doing a partial search ("NOSH") make sure to use `LookAt:=xlPart` instead of `LookAt:=xlWhole`. 
Also in your case, if you want to copy the columns use `WkSh_Q.Columns(rZelle.Column).Copy Destination:=WkSh_Z.Columns(iZeile)` instead of `WkSh_Q.Rows(rZelle.Row).Copy Destination:=WkSh_Z.Rows(iZeile)`

```
Dim WkSh_Q As Worksheet, WkSh_Z As Worksheet
Dim rZelle As Range, aUeberschr As String
Dim strErste As String
Dim iZeile As Integer

aUeberschr = "NOSH"

Set WkSh_Q = Worksheets("Tabelle1") ' das Quell-Tabellenblatt
Set WkSh_Z = Worksheets("Tabelle2") ' das Ziel-Tabellenblatt

With WkSh_Q.Cells

        Set rZelle = .Find(aUeberschr, LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not rZelle Is Nothing Then
            strErste = rZelle.Address
            Do
                iZeile = iZeile + 1
                WkSh_Q.Columns(rZelle.Column).Copy Destination:=WkSh_Z.Columns(iZeile)
                Set rZelle = .FindNext(rZelle)
            Loop Until strErste = rZelle.Address
        End If
End With
```

Hope that helps, good luck.

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy holidays to you too. =)